# Why is a sympathizer of a party the party itself

Tags: germany, marxism, leninism

In German Federal elections (my country) there is a radical left-wing party called MLPD (Marxists Leninists Party of Germany). They choose to not stand for election alone, they have joined a league of organizations.

One of the organizations in the league is the [Sympathizers of the PFLP](http://www.internationalistische-liste.de/?page_id=52) (Popular Front for the Liberation of Palestine). But the other German parties criticize the presence the [PFLP itself in the league](http://www.jpost.com/BDS-THREAT/Palestinian-terror-group-campaigns-to-enter-Bundestag-503539). The other league organizations defend the existence of the Sympathizers of the PFLP inside of the league.

Is there a difference between Sympathizers of PFLP and the PFLP party itself?

Comment: I've changed Sympathant to sympathizer, as I think this is the correct English translation, also "Bundestagswahl" to Federal election.  Please check that these translations are correct.

Comment: @PeterRader What has this question to do with the press?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion stems from the fact that the MLPD changed their homepage. [It used to say PFLP](https://www.vice.com/de/article/ywwjgx/terrorsympathisanten-konnten-bald-deutsche-steuergelder-erhalten), but now it says "Symphatisanten der PFLP" ("PFLP" links to the official PFLP website):

[image: comparison of mlpd website]

The MLPD says that the previous entry was a mistake.

The MLPD further stated that they do not consider the PFLP a terrorist organization because 1) They say the source for it is the Hamas, which is a "fascist terrorist organization" and as such not reliable 2) They do not accept the designation by the EU because the EU is an "imperialistic alliance of states". Because of this, they see no need to distance themselves from the PFLP itself (or the sympathizers, obviously).

In a [blog post](http://www.internationalistische-liste.de/?p=1765), the MLPD states that the PFLP is not part of their alliance, nor are members of the PFLP part of it.

The [PFLP](http://pflp.ps/english/2017/09/02/pflp-statement-on-german-federal-bundestag-elections/) also says that they do not run or participate in the German election and that the Symphatisanten are not affiliated with them. They put the blame for the story on "zionists" and far-right organizations.

Comment: It sure looks like the MLPD is trying to skirt the edge of the law, as they are trying to be as close to a terrorist organization as they can, without being an actual one. The MLPD may not recognize the EU, but the MPLD sure wants to be recognized by the EU and its member states.

Comment: @MSalters I'm not sure if the law is all that relevant here (the PFLP isn't actually outlawed in Germany); that might make for an interesting question. The MLPD is certainly on the edge of common decency by being affiliated with an antisemitic terrorist organization though.

Comment: @PeterRader They declared themselves responsible for attacking a synagogue in 2014. Even if you believe that there can be an antizionism that is not antisemitic, it doesn't include murdering Jews in their places of worship.

Comment: @tim About 2014 exists different statements like "But we have not received any confirmation that it was planned by the PFLP, even though it was consistent with the history of the PFLP," Mizher said. " at https://www.alaraby.co.uk/english/news/2014/11/18/synagogue-attack-israel-vows-retribution-demolishes-palestinian-homes … But all statements exposes the bless of the PFLP to this attack.

Comment: @Grim Zionism is the Jewish self-determination movement, aiming for creation of s Jewish state. Obviously, like any independence movement, it is nationalistic to the extent that  it is grounded in the mainstream concept of a nation-state. Most of the modern states arose this way, especially in Europe. The exception are those few who were the dominant imperial or colonial powers throughout the centuries. It is easy to thrown at self-determination when you are Russian, French or British, but less so, if you are Ukrainian or Polish or Finnish.

Comment: @RogerVadim I a not sure what you meen by "Obviously, like any independence movement" do you mean *any* or *every*?